# How to split polygon exactly in half in MapInfo Pro?

Tags: polygon, mapinfo, splitting

Is there any way to cut a polygon in half in MapInfo Pro?

I want to split thin and long polygon into equal parts along.

Comment: How do you define "equal parts" generally?

Comment: [url=https://postimg.org/image/ausvjb01l/][img]https://s28.postimg.org/ausvjb01l/poligon.png[/img][/url]

Comment: You may find an answer by reading these http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=skeleton

Answer (score 1):

First draw an object to use as the 'cutter', this needs to be a polyline object and can be drawn onto the cosmetic layer. Now, select the object you want to split and make sure it's layer is set to editable. On the menu select `Objects -> Set Target`, this will add a hatched pattern to the object you want to split. Now select the cutter object and on the menu select `Objects -> Polyline Split`, as your cutter is a polyline.

To split the polygon equally you're going to have to do some measuring with the ruler tool and work out the start and end coordinates for your polyline. You could even use a couple of points on the cosmetic layer to snap to which would help to get an accurate split if you set these to coordinates calculated to return a line that bisects your polygon perfectly. The image below should give you an idea of what I mean.

[image]

The above is obviously a very simple example. If your target object does not sit perpendicular to or parallel with either axis then you will need to do a bit of calculation to determine the correct start and end coordinates of your polyline (difference in X and difference in Y of two corners should give you the midpoint of the segment).